# Getting only the data from the first day of the week to the current day of the week

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date, where-clause

So I want to select all my row that is recorded by this week.

For example. today is January 30 2019, which is Wednesday. I would like to select all my row from Monday(January 28,2019) to Wednesday only(current day). And when tomorrow comes, the rows added on Thursday will also be selected.

This will continue til Sunday. And when the Next week Monday comes, it will only select the rows recorded on that Monday. (February 4, 2019) and so on.

I just need to get the (THIS WEEK) data, not the past 7 days.

```
I have a dateadded column

-----------------------------
Firstname|Lastname|dateadded
Michael  |Jordan  |2019-02-03       <-(Feb 3, 2019)
Mark     |Perez   |2019-01-30
Paul     |George  |2019-01-28
John     |Wayne   |2019-01-25
-----------------------------
```

A query that will only select this weeks added data. 
Mark Perez and Paul George which is in the same week of the current day.

```
select * from names WHERE  YEARWEEK(`dateadded`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)
```

will only select the last 7 days of the curdate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can use `WEEKDAY()` to get the day number of the current day within the week, and susbstract if from the current date :

```
SELECT SUBDATE(CURDATE(), WEEKDAY(CURDATE()))
```

Yields :

```
2019-01-28
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=382b00ceb781fbc814135c26a31f8dc5)**

---

As commented by [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9473764/nick), here is an example of a query that uses the above approach to filter a table :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test t
WHERE t.idate >= SUBDATE(CURDATE(), WEEKDAY(CURDATE()))
ORDER BY t.idate
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=59d4b08976cf7a36f93b6ee1fd1d8a33)**

Comment: I think OP probably wants an answer something like https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=59d4b08976cf7a36f93b6ee1fd1d8a33

Comment: @Nick : thank you... I updated my answer with your query and fiddle as well.

Comment: No worries, didn't see any point in posting that myself since you'd already nailed the most important part of the query

Answer (score 0):

You have example of how your table looks?
You could insert records with date and week numbers.
If you record days by week numbers it's easy like :

SELECT * FROM weektable WHERE weekno='5';

.. There are 52 weeks in a year ..

This will select everything from week number 5 and will be adding new rows from same week number automatically.

Comment: ... and all ~5.6 years 53 weeks.